# SQL WHERE query only works on some columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql database called `users` and within a table called `accounts`. In the table `accounts`, there are four columns:`username`, `id`, `hash` and `admin`.

> For example it might look like this: USERNAME: "Account1", ID:
>   "wfi41d", HASH: "h2781rfh", ADMIN "1"

The username is a primary column and what I am trying to do is that via PHP connect to the sql database and by entering the `username` you get the `id`, `hash` and `admin` columns.

Below is **my PHP code** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','users');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"accounts"); 
$username = "Account1"; 
$sql="SELECT username, hash, admin FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$username."'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
echo $data['hash']; //This does not work for ID
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

However the problem is that if I try to fetch the `ID` there is no result.

Only `hash` and `admin` works. Really can't seem to find the issue so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, if you don't select `ID`, you can't retrieve `ID`.

Comment: Are you sure your table has an id column? Are you connecting to the correct DB? Have you modified your SQL to retrieve the id column as well?

Comment: Could the data type for username have trailing spaces? Try: $sql="SELECT username, hash, admin FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE '".$username."%'";

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not select `ID` field.
just replace this:

```
$sql="SELECT username, hash, admin FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$username."'";
```

line with

```
$sql="SELECT username, id, hash, admin FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$username."'";
```

Comment: @S.Doe If you helped from this answer please up vote the answer so that others can also get little help and tick the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Id as the primary. And $sql"Select username, hash, admin From accounts Where username Like'".$username."%"';
GoodLuck! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you're after all four columns, in this case why not use the `*` selector:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '".$username."'";
```

That will return all column values - which it looks as though you're after anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT username, id, hash, admin FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username'";
```

or

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '$username'";
```

may this will helps ....